# How handle metadata api changes in Apex? (Ex: insert/update ApexClass)

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-communities, sfdc-metadata-api

I trying to find a solution how to handle any metadata changes in Salesforce using Apex. At the moment my main goal handle changes in any `ApexClass` record. I need to have the ability to understand that `ApexClass` was updated and get `ApexClass` Body in my future service method in moment upsert OR delete `ApexClass`.

Do you have idea how I can do that?

Thanks in advance!

I tried use Trigger - Implement Trigger for `ApexClass` is forbidden

Answer (score 0):

We don't insert/upsert/delete classes, we deploy changes to them with Metadata API. I don't think you can hook any automation to that.

You could create a scheduled job that checks SetupAuditTrail or ApexClass/ApexTrigger or DeployResult tables. You could check Event Monitoring's documentation, there's something about Metadata events (but I think it'll be just a log after the fact, it won't emit a platform event the moment deployment occurs)

In a way you're solving it in wrong place. Ban everybody from deploying directly to production and hook something to your CI job (Circle CI, Github actions, gearset, azure devops, copado... what have you)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but my goal makes sense only in handling the API metadata event in the executing moment, without any CI\CD, etc.